# HttpClient ignoring encoding, on a single computer

Tags: java, character-encoding, apache-commons-httpclient

I am using HttpClient (version 3.1) on several different (but apparently identical) computers to read a UTF-8 encoded JSON data from a URL.

On all the machines, save one, it works fine.  I have some Spanish language words and they come through with accents and tildes intact.

One computer stubbornly refuses to cooperate.  It is apparently treating the data as ISO-8859-1, despite a `Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8` header.

If I use `curl` to access that URL from that computer, it works correctly.  On every other computer, both curl and my HttpClient-based program work correctly.

I did an md5sum on the common-httpclient.jar file on each machine: the same.

Is there some setting, deep in Linux, that might be different and be messing with me?  Any other theories, or even places to look?

**EDIT:** some people asked for more details.

Originally I had the problem deep in the bowels of a complex Tomcat app, but I lightly adapted [the sample](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html) to just retrieve the URL in question, and (fortunately) had the same problem.

These are Linux 2.6 machines running jdk1.7.0_45.

An `env` command yields a bunch of variables.  The only one that looks remotely on point is `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`.

Comment: may you explain a little more about the machine on which it isn't working, that's a linux? which one?

Comment: Can you clarify the setup? Is problem with command line client that uses httpclient to access some URL? What locale system environmental variables are set on this computer?

Comment: @caramba answer in edit.

Comment: How are you then *viewing* the results? Can you post a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem? (You talk about the sample in the HttpClient docs - are you saying you *just* need to change the URL in there? Note that the sample uses the platform-default encoding, which is a bad idea.) Can you save the *binary* data to a file, and compare that with what curl downloads? That would isolate the problem.

Comment: Do you use SpringMVC on your serverside Controller?

Comment: why is it Content-Type: application/json and not Content-Type= application/json?

Comment: Almost certainly the system character set that the JVM ends up using is different on that one machine.  The following ServerFault question may be relevant:  http://serverfault.com/questions/149071/how-can-be-changed-the-linux-systems-default-character-set

Comment: Did you try setting charset=UTF-8. Linux might be case sensitive, although the UTF-8 is the default for JSON data. Also, did you try with different browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Opera,...) on same machine? Same result?

Answer (score 5):

How do you get the json response data from HttpClient?

If you get it back in binary form (through `getResponseBodyAsStream()` for example), and then convert it to a String without specifying charset, then the result depends on your JVM's default charset.

You can check the value of JVM default charset by:

```
Charset.defaultCharset().name()
```

This might give "UTF-8" on all machines except the one failing.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your code, it is difficult to say what's wrong, but here is a "correct" way of doing this (using HttpClient 3.1.0 for request and Jackson 2.1.3 to parse the JSON).

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
GetMethod get = new GetMethod(uri);
int status = hc.executeMethod(get);
if (status != HttpStatus.SC_OK) throw new RuntimeException("http status " + status);
ObjectMapper jsonParser = new ObjectMapper(new JsonFactory());
// we use an InputStreamReader with explicit charset to read the response body
JsonNode json = jsonParser.readTree(
    new InputStreamReader(get.getResponseBodyAsStream(), get.getResponseCharSet())
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I already faced this issue and this was because of the encoding type configured in the client. So I had to make a "work around" like the one below:

```
String encmsg = new String(respStr.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), java.nio.charset.Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

It reads the String as ISO-8859-1 and convert to UTF-8.